# Bokeh server deconstructor

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I'm running a Bokeh server, is there a deconstructor that is run when closing a web page run from the server?

Im polling data from a database and wanna close the connection to the database when the web page is closed. Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want the `on_session_destroyed` lifecycle hook:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#lifecycle-hooks